# How to iterate array value by comparing it with another array in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
      <div>
        <div v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.sname">
          <BaseAccordian>
            <template v-slot:title>{{ box.sname }}</template>
            <template v-slot:content>
              <div v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.tname" class="line">
                <List :content="matchingdata" :sname="box.sname" />
              </div>
            </template>
          </BaseAccordian>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template> 

    <script>
    import BaseAccordian from "./BaseAccordian.vue";
    import List from "./List.vue";
    export default {
      name: "HelloWorld",
      components: {
        BaseAccordian,
        List,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          boxes: [
            {
              sname: "apple",
            },
            {
              sname: "bananna",
            },
            {
              sname: "grapes",
            },
            {
              sname: "choc",
            },
          ],

          paints: [
            {
              tname: "a",
            },
            {
              tname: "b",
            },
            {
              tname: "c",
            },
            {
              tname: "d",
            },
            {
              tname: "e",
            },
          ],

          matchingdata: [
            {
              matchid: "1",
              OverallStatus: "ok",
              sname: "choc",
            },
            {
              matchid: "2",
              OverallStatus: "notok",
              sname: "grapes",
            },
          ],
        };
      },
    };
    </script>
```

**BaseAccordion.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="accordion">
          <input type="checkbox" @click="toggleItem" />
          <h2 class="title">
            <slot name="title"></slot>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div v-show="show" class="content">
          <slot name="content"></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      components: {},
      data: function () {
        return {
          show: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        toggleItem: function () {
          this.show = !this.show;
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

**List.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div class="">
        <div
          v-for="match in matchingData"
          :key="match.matchid"
          :class="{
            green: match.OverallStatus === 'ok',
            red: match.OverallStatus === 'notok',
          }"
        >
          {{ match.OverallStatus }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      components: {},
      props: {
        content: {
          type: Array,
          required: true,
        },
        sname: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
      data: function () {
        return {};
      },
      methods: {},
      computed: {
            matchingData() {
      return this.content.filter((a) => {
        if (a.sname === this.sname) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    },
      },
    };
    </script>
    <style scoped>
    </style>
```

I three arrays called **matchingdata,boxes,paints** array based on this three arrays, i am trying to filter the array.(nested  v-for)

**Now, I want to iterate the **matchingdata** array by comparing it with sname in boxes array. and Common value between matchingdata and boxes array is ""sname""**

I tried above logic, and struck with computed property.

**Expected Output:-**

In List.vue component , i have
{{ match.OverallStatus }} where that field , i want to show,(from the matchingdata array) when user clicked on checkbox.

Taking the  ""sname"" the common value from the matchingdata array and the boxes array

code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-pine-27s2kn?file=/src/components/List.vue

Comment: What comparison are you trying to make between matchingdata ans boxex? There is no common value between object in these arrays? Whats your expected output?

Comment: Common  value between matchingdata and boxes array is **sname**

https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-pine-27s2kn?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Expected output is, When clicked on checkbox, I want to show {{ match.OverallStatus }}  from the matchingdata array... from the list.vue component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're passing the **sname** property as a string via a prop to your **List.vue** component, you'll just need to use that string in your filter function.

```
matchingData() {
   return this.content.filter((a) => a.sname === this.sname)
},
```

I've tried this in your codesandbox link and it is giving some output - but I'm not clear enough on what you're trying to achieve to know if this is the intended outcome.

Just incase you're not aware the 'filter' function returns a new array. It's not going to return a 'true/false' which I feel you may be trying to do.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: This is how , i am getting output now, after the changes suggested. https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-pine-27s2kn?file=/src/components/List.vue

in the output, if i click on chocs, grapes , i am getting 4 lines?? stating for one as ok, and for other as not ok

Comment: But after clicking the grapes and chocs from the output , I am getting duplicate data.( data printing 4 times as ok and not ok) Can it show like,

Comment: Functionality should be like, if **sname** in the boxes and **sname** in the matchingdata matches then show only particular status inside of the each sname else show as no data.

Comment: It's showing 5 times because you're including the List.vue component inside a v-for loop of 'paints' which has 5 items (in your HelloWorld.vue). Again I'm not sure what the intended outcome is (with the paints), but removing that v-for loop of 'paints' achieves what you're describing.

Comment: Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-saha-j7gvrv?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: <template v-slot:content>
          <div v-if="" v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.tname" class="line">
            <List :content="matchingdata" :sname="box.sname" />
          </div>
          <div v-else>No data found</div>
        </template>

Can i add v-if and else condition to the v-for? for example like **is it possible to show message where particular sname has no data in it.??**

Comment: Yes, I've updated my codesandbox example.

Comment: Thanks, One last suggestion please I just added **class="line"** inside **<List :content="matchingdata" :sname="box.sname" class="line" />**

Then having small issue like,  if for **no data message** also it is drawing line.  and the {{match.overallstatus)) color schould apply to lines also, but it is not applying.

Here is the code after changes https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-jennings-tcr8oj?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Apply the line class dynamically within the List.vue module, if you just apply it to the component then of course it will appear every time. You've done similar with the :class already so I feel you can manage this. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Got it. :)